# Putting a specific value from a file into a database

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, text-files

this question might be dump, but I'm seriosly out of ideas right now.
Alright, I've got a strange .txt file. Looks something like this

```
VA1*31860*489*31860*489
VA3*0*0*0*0
```

I need the value which is behind VA1. So the 31860.
Reading the file and putting some values inside the database is not a problem, but finding the value is.
The value is not at the same place and row everytime, it changes pretty often.

My ideas are string splitting, regex..but I've got no idea how to get them to work.

Comment: Can you expand on 'The value is not at the same place and row everytime'

Comment: If you have no idea, the solution is to do research.  Skitter over to MSDN and read up on `String.Split`.  Hint: If you can find the 'key' can you just look at the value in the next index?

Comment: the textfile is a outputfile of an machine. so there's the possibility that va1*xxx*x*x*x is on row 53 instead of 12.

string.split sounds good, gonna look into it.

Answer (score 1):

so, I think you want something like:

```
For Each line As String in file.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    If line.StartsWith("VA1") Then
            Dim value as string = line.Split("*"c)(1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

(don't forget to add some error handling - what if the VA1 line doesn't have any *s in it, etc. I'm assuming the VA1 is at the start of a line, and the file is generated with the same line-endings as the environment of the app being run)

Comment: that works! yesterday I've got an solution with regex (search for VA1*c), but it also puts the VA1 out. this one is much cleaner, thanks